# Is there a way of displaying backordered items on a Netsuite advanced PDF Packing Slip (freemarker)?

Tags: if-statement, netsuite, freemarker

Basiscally we have a freemarker form (netsuite calls it Advanced PDF) for a Packing List. It displays the items shipped, with quantity ordered, quantity shipped, and quantity backordered - easy.
Keep in mind, it needs to respect previous shipments, so it doesn't displays items already fulfilled.
The problem is, in the process of excluding previous shipments, it excludes backordered items which haven't been shipped yet, and we would like these to display as X ordered, 0 shipped, X backordered.

Have a look at the segment below - so far I've tried adding an #elseif for when quantitybackorder+quantitycommitted gt 0, but this literally repeats each line on the fulfillment by the number of lines on the order, which is strange (ie. 8 lines ordered, 2 fulfilled- those 2 will repeat 8 times each, with each set of data on its own line)

```
<#if record.item?has_content>
            <table class="itemtable"><!-- start items -->
            <#list record.item as item>
                <#if item_index==0>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="5" style="align: left;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Item Number</span></th>
                            <th colspan="12" style="align: left;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Item Description</span></th>
                            <th colspan="3"><span style="font-size:12px;">Ordered</span></th>
                            <th colspan="3"><span style="font-size:12px;">Backorder</span></th>
                            <th colspan="3"><span style="font-size:12px;">Shipped</span></th>
                            <th colspan="2"><span style="font-size:12px;">Unit</span></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </#if>
                <#list salesorder.item as tranline>
                    <#if tranline.custcol_item_code==item.item>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5"><p style="text-align: left;">${item.item}</p></td>
                                <td colspan="12"><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px;">${item.description}</span><br /><em>${tranline.custcol_extra_details}</em></p></td>
                                <td colspan="3" style="align: center;">${tranline.quantity}</td>
                                <td colspan="3" style="align: center;">${tranline.quantitybackordered+tranline.quantitycommitted}</td>
                                <td colspan="3" style="align: center;">${item.quantity}</td>
                                <td colspan="2" style="align: center;">${tranline.units}</td>
                            </tr>
                    </#if>
                </#list>
            </#list>
    <!-- end items --></table>
</#if>
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can allow for backordered items here, or looking at it another way, just exclude the already fulfilled items leaving current fulfillment and backorders?
Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: You can see how to do this in the example on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546879/netsuite-field-ids-not-printing-on-advanced-pdf/56549863#56549863

Comment: @bknights thanks for your reply - what you've got there seems to make sense, and with a bit of tweaking I was hoping it would work in my case, but tweaked or untweaked, it returns the same error as Jake Pearson was getting in the one you refer to. And in answer to your question there - yes, we do have a scripted Print function.

Comment: Is it possible the line item it fails on is not  an inventory item or is not fulfillable? If so (and this is the fix anyway) you need to test for whether that value is a number.  Syntax change might be as simple a `<#assign prevShipped=tranline.quantityfulfilled?number>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to do it, apart from my earlier answer, is to define shippednow as 0 before you start, then draw data without giving it the option of being zero. This avoids getting an indexing issue on the first line.

```
        <#list salesorder.item as tranline><#assign shippednow=0 >
          <#list record.item as item><#if item.orderline==tranline.line><#assign shippednow=item.quantity ></#if></#list><#assign prevship=tranline.quantityfulfilled-shippednow>
            <#if tranline.quantity==(prevship!0)><#else>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5"><p style="text-align: left;">${tranline.custcol_item_code}</p></td>
                        <td colspan="12"><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px;">${tranline.description}</span><br /><em>${tranline.custcol_extra_details}</em></p></td>
                        <td colspan="3" style="align: center;"><#if tranline.quantity gt 0>${tranline.quantity}<#else>0</#if></td>
                        <td colspan="3" style="align: center;">${(tranline.quantitybackordered+tranline.quantitycommitted)?string.number}</td>
                        <td colspan="3" style="align: center;">${shippednow!"0"}</td>
                        <td colspan="2" style="align: center;">${tranline.units}</td>
                      </tr></#if>
        </#list>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it was a non-fulfillable issue, and what you've got there would fix it. I've actually moved away from that, because the pair of lists for some reason was making all the lines double-up. What I've ended up with is:

```
<#list salesorder.item as tranline>
    <#list record.item as item>
        <#if tranline.custcol_item_code==item.custcol_item_code><#assign shippednow=item.quantity ><#else><#assign shippednow=0 ></#if>
    </#list>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"><p style="text-align: left;">${tranline.custcol_item_code}</p></td>
        <td colspan="12"><p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px;">${tranline.description}</span><br /><em>${tranline.custcol_extra_details}</em></p></td>
        <td colspan="3" style="align: center;"><#if tranline.quantity gt 0>${tranline.quantity}<#else>0</#if></td>
        <td colspan="3" style="align: center;">${tranline.quantitybackordered+tranline.quantitycommitted}</td>
        <td colspan="3" style="align: center;">${shippednow}</td>
        <td colspan="2" style="align: center;">${tranline.units}</td>
    </tr>
</#list>
```

Comment: I thought the above would solve my problems, only there's one unforeseen problem - the first line on every printed form, regardless of how many items, shows a shipped quantity of 0. I can't see any reason for it, but does anyone know why that one line always shows `shipped = 0`?

Comment: Still can't find a reason for it - does anyone have any ideas?